# How to decide merge order schemas graphql codegen

Tags: graphql, graphql-codegen, graphql-schema

I'm trying to merge two separate graphql schemas one which is provided by my CMS endpoint and a local schema for additional typehinting (my CMS schema isn't precise enough).

Is there a way to configure the merge order in the graphql codegen config?

I've been able to merge both schemas and handle the override however my online schema is overriding the local one instead of the other way around.

I've used [the following thread](https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/issues/3451#issuecomment-1266245636) as a reference for my code however they've got the same issue.